# Properly Configure Video Driver on Ubuntu Mate 16.04 on VirtualBox (mac)

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, intel-graphics, macosx, ubuntu-mate

Seems I wasn't able to properly configure video driver for Ubuntu Mate installed on Virtual Box on mac.

I see that guest additions are working (clipboard, window resizing, etc.), but when I'm opening for example Firefox it is very slow on rendering.

Anything I missed?
Any suggestions?

I've properly installed Guest addition tools.
Here is some video config info.

```
~/Desktop $ sudo lshw -c video 
*-display               
  description: VGA compatible controller
  product: VirtualBox Graphics Adapter
  vendor: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH
  physical id: 2
  bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
  version: 00
  width: 32 bits
  clock: 33MHz
  capabilities: vga_controller bus_master rom
  configuration: driver=vboxvideo latency=0      resources: irq:18 
  memory:e0000000-e7ffffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

I'm using:

- Machine: Macbook Pro 13" 2017
- Graphic: Intel Iris Plus Graphics 650 1536 MB
- VirtualBox: 5.1.26
- 3D Acceleration is enabled
- 128 MB Allocated Video Memory
- 8GB Allocated RAM
- Ubuntu Mate 16.04

Answer (score 0):

I just had problem with VirtualBox on my 2016 13" MBP when the whole system was very slow and laggy. I used the same settings as you. I solved the issue by using Parallels Desktop Lite from App Store instead of VirtualBox. It is for free when you are only going to use Linux and runs very smooth. Hopefully it helps

Comment: Thanks for the response, I also stopped on Parallels Desktop, which produce incomparable result over Vbox in this case.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be for free any more (Feb 2019).